# Dos aplicaciones en un mismo servidor y se cruzan las conexiones a BD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo dos aplicaciones en un solo servidor, APP1 Y APP2, cada una con su propia base de datos, de un momento a otro entro a APP2 y me aparece la información de la Base de datos de APP1, tienen diferente app_key, le puse a una un cache driver diferente, le cambia a una el nombre de session por cookie, no sé por qué empieza a tomar la conexión de la otra.

Archivos solicitados
[https://github.com/workspacedg/StackOverflowLaravel]

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:pE+ZHzpoaj0/F/mFXiVGUQUw8B/gUEQ0uVXfff
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db1
DB_USERNAME=udb1
DB_PASSWORD=clavedb1

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

--

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:LxzLj5z0pvrDRavViw9NtmoYuasdlkfñasjkdfla
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db2
DB_USERNAME=udb2
DB_PASSWORD=clave2

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

---

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:8071>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot E:/app1/public
    <Directory  "E:/app1">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8072>
    ServerName app2
    DocumentRoot E:/app2/public
    <Directory  "E:/app2">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ¿Tienen URLs distintas? podemos ver los contenidos de config/database.php? ¿puedes contarnos más de la estructura de las dos aplicaciones y cómo están "instaladas"? Necesitamos más información para poderte ayudar.

Comment: @Shaz la urls son app1:8071 y app:8072 , cada una tiene su repositorio de laravel y esta en carpetas separadas , config/database en cada una esta por defecto , aqui subo archivos [https://github.com/workspacedg/StackOverflowLaravel]

Comment: @shaz si necesita ver otro archivo me avisa, muchas gracias

Comment: Que raro, yo tengo varias aplicaciones en el mismo servidor sin problema, ¿le cambiaste el nombre a la cookie? Veo que usas el mismo `APP_URL` para ambas aplicaciones.

Comment: @Shaz a uno le tengo  'cookie' => 'laravel_session', y al otro  'cookie' => 'laravel_session_app2',  puede ser por el APP_URL=http://localhost ?

Comment: @Shaz le cambia la APP_URL parece que funciona ya solo queda esperar como califico su respuesta que fue de ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resumen**

Cambia el parámetro `APP_URL` de tu archivo .env para reflejar la URL real de cada aplicación.

**Explicación**

Varios comandos y herramientas de Laravel como Artisan, los jobs, CLI, así como varios helpers de enrutamiento y en general todo lo que tenga que ver con rutas como Facades, Service Providers, entre otros, utilizan el valor del parámetro `APP_URL` para generar valores que son reutilizados en muchos "puntos" de la aplicación, de ahí la importancia de definir la URL específica y real de cada app.